# Jenkins Pipeline Slack Two Way Step Interaction

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm building a declarative Jenkins Pipeline and after I have completed a few testing steps, I would like to have a step that notifies a slack channel that a build is ready to proceed to production. If that slack post is not responded to for a fixed amount of time, I would like Slack to notify Jenkins Pipeline to continue to the next step. If a fixed reply "ABORT" replies to the Slack post, I would like for Slack to communicate back to the Jenkins pipeline to abort the build. Any ideas on how to accomplish this two way interaction between Slack and Jenkins Pipeline?

```
node {
    stage('build'){
        echo "building"
    }
}
stage('Deploy approval'){
    input "Deploy to prod?"
}
node {
    stage('deploy to prod'){
        echo "deploying"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do it directly . What you can do it is you can divide your jobs into two or three jobs and send notification at the end of first job using a function like this :

```
def notifySlack(text, channel) {
def slackURL = ' https://hooks.slack.com/services/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'
def payload = JsonOutput.toJson([text      : text,
                                 channel   : channel,
                                 username  : "jenkins",
                                 icon_emoji: ":jenkins:"])
sh "curl -X POST --data-urlencode \'payload=${payload}\' ${slackURL}"
```

}

then in slack you can write a script to build another part of your job (which is actually a new job) using slash commands :https://github.com/auth0/slash#inputs-and-outputs

This could be accomplished writing a php or any server side code and sending it paramaters where you can send ABORT and in the job you have to build , have a parameter to check the value of this passed parameter and have a condition according to it .